# Voip telephone systems using SIP for home use

Tags: telephony

I want to buy a voip telephone device, through which I can make cheap international calls. This is possible over various iPhone and Android apps, but since the calls are mostly from the office, I would like to buy a dedicated device for the same.

The device should have a capability to connect to the internet using wifi or an ethernet port ( prefer ethernet port, since the phone will be permanently on the desk )

I found a manual from the provider ( where I have made an account and enabled the SIP server settings ) - https://www.dialnow.com/sip. But, I cant quite understand which kind of device I should buy.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about "kind of device", and for that the answer is **any SIP phone.**

**SIP** is a protocol/standard and every service or device that comply with these standards are usually compatible.

There are two types of SIP phones you can use.

1. a SIP desk phone with an LCD display and all kind of physical keys for the options.
2. a SIP ATA adapter, which lets you configure it with a SIP service and connect to it an old style phone.

For the first type I'd personally say the [**Yealink SIP-T46S**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MYPIQMC) is a great option (make sure to buy a power adapter if you do not have PoE ethernet.) And for the 2nd type something like the [**Obihai OBi200**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUV7C9A) (works also with Google Voice) or the [**Cisco SPA112**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00684PN54).

Answer (score 0):

I have purchased a Grandstream GXP2200 several years ago and am quite happy with it. This is a table-top phone which runs Android and connects to your LAN via Ethernet or Wifi. It supports all common Android features and you can even install apps. The only downside is that they are really slow updating the Android version. Mine has still 2.3, and their current line is on Android 4.2!

But they have a line of cheaper SIP table-top phones which seem to have a different OS. They still have a bunch of nice features (e.g. managing multiple SIP accounts) and they are sold for 25 Euros (GXP1610) to 60 Euros (GXP1630) on Amazon.

http://www.grandstream.com/products/ip-voice-telephony/basic-ip-phones